# Accessed Denied when saving a plot as both image or pdf?

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, rstudio

I'm trying to save a plot, but my "Save as Image..." AND my "Save as PDF..." both have a box pop up that just says "Access Denied".

Does anyone have an idea on what is going wrong? I've already updated all my packages, and tried turning R on and off again..

Comment: Please edit your question with a reproducible example, code you are using, and data.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a question arising from actions in Rstudio. The messages suggest you do not have operating system priveleges to save files to whatever undisclosed destinations your GUI is pointing at when you do this. Try changing the directory. (But because so few comments get acted on substantively, also voting to close as unclear.)

Comment: #sample df, cannot save in GUI but can save rcode file 
df <- data.frame("x" = 1:6, "y" = 7:12)
df <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x, fill = y))
df